# Search a value in two different fields with QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I'm using Spring Boot and QueryDSL to do REST requests but I'm having problems to do a search that performs a query with the same value in two fields (to clarify, if a value is in a field OR another). Something like that:

```
select * from news where title like '%word%' or content like '%word%';
```

And I want to do a request like this (not strictly, could be something different):

```
http://localhost?title=word&content=word
```

I have this in my RestController:

```
@GetMapping
public PagedResources<Resource> get(@QuerydslPredicate(root = News.class) Predicate predicate,
                                    @SortDefaults({
                                        @SortDefault(sort = "type", direction = ASC),
                                        @SortDefault(sort = "dateCreated", direction = DESC)
                                    }) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<News> pages = newsService.getAllWithPagination(predicate, pageable);
    return pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(pages, newsResourceAssembler);
}
```

And this is my repository:

```
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<News>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QNews> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QNews news) {
        bindings.bind(String.class)
            .first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
}
```

}

I'm tired of searching and I didn't find anyone that have done something similar. Anyone have any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

QNews qnews = QNews.news;
final BooleanExpression booleanExpression = qnews.title.like("%word%").or(qnews .content.like("%word%"));

> just before do this check null values in queryparam

Comment: Not exact answer to my question but pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the @kumar answer and more research I finally achieve what I want:

```
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QNews news) {
    bindings.bind(news.title)
        .first((path, value) -> path.likeIgnoreCase("%" + value + "%").or(news.content.likeIgnoreCase("%" + value + "%")));
}
```